# Visual Studio (Or TFS) randomly adding weird bits in .config file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've been seeing some strange issues with `*.config` files merged through TFS and Visual Studio.

In some cases, specially when the file is new, the `add` tags in the `appsetting` tags have weird bits in the `value` properties. I uploaded a example [here](https://pastebin.com/V7attbV0).

These bits are not visible in the following text editors:

- Visual Studio
- Notepad
- Notepad++ - Tried in both encodings (ANSI and UTF8(with or without BOM)) and the bits didn't show in either one.

In these, seemingly, all is fine.

However, on VIM (I just remembered about its existence now, writing this post):

[image]

This is a major problem: Mainly on `app.config`, when a Windows Service reads it, these values often accompany the weird bits.

For example, if I try to run, in a Windows Service, with that `app.config` file

```
int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HorarioProcessamentoMudarFila"], out int changingHour);
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HorarioProcessamentoMudarFila"])
```

`TryParse` fails, and `Console` exhibits "??7??". (note the "7" in the middle of the "?").

When I run this code in LINQPad

```
File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\fileName.txt").Select((i, o) => new { 
    index = o,
    value = i,      
    ansi = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { i }),
    utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { i}),         
    t = (char)i
}).Dump();
```

[image]

I can see that in the ANSI encoding, these bits translate to `â€ª` and `â€¬` , so it appears to be some sort of control delimiter.

Is there a known issue here? Where did these bits seemingly come from?

EDIT: Clarified the usage of Notepad++.

Comment: Could you share how to reproduce your issue with detailed steps?

Comment: Why are you using ANSI? TFS uses UTF-8 by default, this will cause some weird issues.  Is there a reason for ANSI?

Comment: @Etienne None. I did not set it to use ANSI, and it seems that, unlike TFS, VSTS _does_ use ANSI by default.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT unfortunately, although I have seen this issue a few times, I have never been able to pinpoint the steps I took to reach this stage. Normally, it happened when a config file was created in lower branches, and was merged up to the staging areas.

Comment: @Etienne also, I tried ANSI alongside with UTF8 to try to find in which of these encodings those bits meant something.

Comment: @EricWu Can you download Notepad++ and check the encoding then change it (in notepad++) to UTF8 say and see if your weird characters? Encoding is not fun, and what's saved in TFS is what's brought down on your machine (and hte build server).  So you might want to make sure everything is UTF8 and checkin.

Comment: I did (I stated so in the answer). I checked both the encodings in Notepad ++ (UTF8 and ANSI), and it didn't show those bits in either format. There was only one editor that managed to show theses bits, and it was VIM.

Comment: when you do a get latest in a new folder an open them with notepad++ are the files ANSI or UTF8? If ANSI I would mass modify them all to UTF8 and check everything back in.  See if this makes it better.

Comment: When I do a get latest, they are tagged as UTF8.
In notepad++, when I "force"-convert the files from ANSI to UTF8 (_or vice versa_), nothing weird pops up. In fact, I had given up all hope of visualizing the bits in the editors, and resourced to LINQPad to view them. Only when I started typing this question did I remember that I had VIM (for windows) installed, so I gave it a quick run.

Answer (score 0):

From a Visual Studio Command Prompt, you can type: `tf properties file` (or `tf properties file`) and the **File Type** line will tell you the current encoding. See the [Properties Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/properties-or-info-command?view=azure-devops) for more info.

And [Configure Version Control File Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/properties-or-info-command?view=azure-devops) via Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio to see whether it helps you.

Comment: It does not...I ran it, and it said what I already knew: It is encoded in UTF8. Still, the bits not visible in this encoding, so TFS included them (presumably) in ANSI for mistake. The question remains: _Why_ did it include them?

Comment: How did you create the config file?

Comment: The "Right-click the project, Add File, Configuration File, etc" way.

Comment: Do other team members have this issue? If you create config file on other client machine, are you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am not able to repro this issue, Cece... Unfortunately, it happened way too randomly for me to pinpoint a step-by-step.

Comment: It's hard for us to troubleshoot your issue as we don't have same environment of client machine. Your issue may caused  by the file you created, it seems the file created in other encoding. You may try in other client machine to monitor whether the issue would happen.